# Why does printing a 2D array of characters give garbage values?

Tags: c

I am implementing a function that prints a 2D array of characters only using a double-pointer and pointer notation. When I run the code, it prints a bunch of garbage values in the format I want instead of the correct characters.

My professor instructed me not to use arr[row][col], instead, I must access it using *(*(arr+i)+j) or similar

This is a project for a class and I can't change any of the code outside of this function. The characters are meant to be formatted like a word search puzzle. The arguments passed to my function are `char** arr, int size`.

This is my function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n", *(arr+i), *(arr+i)+1, *(arr+i)+2, *(arr+i)+3, *(arr+i)+4, *(arr+i)+5, *(arr+i)+6, * 
(arr+i)+7, *(arr+i)+8, *(arr+i)+9, *(arr+i)+10, *(arr+i)+11, *(arr+i)+12, *(arr+i)+13, *(arr+i)+14 );   }
```

Expected output:

```
W D B M J Q D B C J N Q P T I
I R Z U X U Z E A O I O R T N
M N Z P L R N H L Y L X H M D
M Y E K A I D P I U L Y O W I
A O A B A R K U F V I H L A A
L O N M R X K I O J N A V R N
A E P T A A R A R T O W A I A
S U C Z A U S I N A I A L Z V
K O T A O N R K I S S I A O N
A H X S V K A I A E A I B N E
U D S X N X C C D W G S A A V
O I S D W L E J N J T X M H A
M O X W T N H Q D X O Q A Q D
R U U V G E O R G I A Q V D A
V F L O R I D A L G L W O X N
```

Actual output:

```
░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛
≡ ± ≥ ≤ ⌠ ⌡ ÷ ≈ ° ∙ · √ ⁿ ² ■

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = >
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^
p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
É æ Æ ô ö ò û ù ÿ Ö Ü ¢ £ ¥ ₧
░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛
╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐
≡ ± ≥ ≤ ⌠ ⌡ ÷ ≈ ° ∙ · √ ⁿ ² ■

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = >
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^
└ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼ ╞ ╟ ╚ ╔ ╩ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬
` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n
```

Comment: Please provide an MVCE

Comment: `arr` appears to be a a pointer to a 1D array of pointers to char arrays.  You need to access characters as `arr[row][col]`

Comment: Looks like you have not initialized `i` in the `for` loop too

Comment: `*(arr+i)` is a pointer to the ith row in `arr`. `*(*(arr + i) + j)` is the ith element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `arr` is really a `char**`, then you need to dereference twice to get a `char`.

So, in your statement, `arr+i` is another `char**`, pointing at a `char*` `i` steps further along from the one `arr` points at. Hopefully `arr` points at the beginning of an array of `char*` at least `size` long.

Now `*(arr+i)` dereferences it, fetching the `char*` pointed to by `arr+i`, giving you a `char*`.

Now `*(arr+i)+7`, for example, is another `char*`, pointing at a `char` 7 steps further along from the one `*(arr+i)` points at. Hopefully `*(arr+i)` points at the beginning of an array of `char` at least 15 long.

But you don't dereference it, so you're attempting to print the value of the pointer (i.e. the address it holds), not the value it points to (the `char`).

Try `*(*(arr+i)+7)`.

Comment: You know, I've been struggling with both learning 2D arrays and pointers at the same time, so that is really helpful! It ended up solving my problem.